# The operation you selected will convert the selected basic disk(s) to dynamic disk(s)

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I was trying to create partition to dual boot Linux but got this error. What does it means? Will it safe to proceed or will it damage my computer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is not an error, it is a warning.

Comment: @DavidPostill yes, it warns that I wont be able to start installed operating system so kinda serious

Comment: @Thang: It says "except the current boot volume".

Answer (score 0):

For a basic disc you exhausted the number of parititions you can have (4). You'd need to delete one and create an extended partition (that can contain more partitions). Converting to a dynamic disc is also an option but will probably not yield a result that will work the way you want.

The most likely that will help you is to convert your disk to GPT. This might still render your Windows unbootable, depending on what hardware you're using. Creating a backup on a secondary disk or similar should be something you do before you proceed as depending on your choice you might need to reinstall Windows.

To convert to a GPT disk you will probably need to boot using a flash drive or similar as you will not be able to convert to GPT while running Windows from the disk you're trying to convert. The option, just like the one to convert to a dynamic disk, is available through the right click menu.